# How to sed to filter the former redundant condition

Tags: shell, sed

here is my sample test.txt for practicing sed

Here is my question

How can I find the red fram by bash shell

I can only type below

how to modify to filter redundant 'vh1'?

```
BillyLiu:Test billyliou$ sed -n '/vh1/,/vh2/p' test.txt 

BillyLiu:Test billyliou$ cat test.txt 
vh1
---
vh1
---
vh1
vh1
vh1
vh1
asdsd
sdsdsds
dsdskjskflkd
sdsfsmdfk
vh2

----
don't want to be found
----

vh1
asdjskldjkalsjd
skdjksjkjk
xijcviorm,nre
vh2
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? We ask that you make an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I only want to show 「red frame」but in this condition ,it will also show other vh1.....
That's my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

```sh
sed -En 'H; ${ g; s/(.*)vh1.*vh2/\1/; p; }' test.txt
```

That reads the whole file into the hold space.
In the `s///` pattern, the leading `.*` is greedy, so this will match the *last* "vh1...vh2" in the file.

The equivalent perl

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.*)vh1.+vh2/$1/s' test.txt
```

requires the `s` flag so that dot matches newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'H;/vh1/h;/vh2/{g;/vh1/p}' file
```

Append all lines to the hold space.

Reset the hold space if a line contains `vh1`.

If a line contains `vh2`, swap it for the hold space and print the hold space if it contains `vh1` too.